# Is there a way in Firebase to get an array of the collections of multiple documents of a parent collection and pass it as props? Firebase Next.js

Tags: javascript, firebase, next.js

I'm trying to retrieve all the collections inside of all the documents of a collection called users.

This is how I retrieve all the users.

```
export async function getServerSideProps() {

const snapshot = await firebase
.firestore()
.collection("users")
.orderBy("points", "desc")
.get();

let users = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
 
...

}
```

What I want, is to get the collections inside those users and save them into an array.

[Firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tywmg.png)

I want to retrieve the all the "quiniela" collections from all the users and pass them as props

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: So to understand better, you need to get all documents of all quiniela" collections that exist within all documents, is that right?

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the `quiniela` collection from each document with `.collection()`.

```js
let users = snapshot.docs.map(async (user) => {
    let quiniela = (await user
        .collection("quiniela")
        .get())
        .map((doc) => doc.data());
    
    return {
        ...user.data(),
        quiniela,
    }
});
```

This should add the document data from the user's `quiniela` collection.

**Note** that `users` will now be a `Promise[]`. If you need to load the data, call:

```js
await Promise.all(users)
```

Comment: I ended up using this:                                                                                                         const quinielas = await Promise.all(
    snapshot3.docs.map(async (doc) => {
      const quiniela = await doc.ref.collection("quiniela").get();
      return quiniela.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
    })
  );         But still, thanks.